# Changing bar-plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Completely newbie here, Im currently trying to plot one student's grades(bar plot) on some assignments versus the mean grades(line plot) derived from the rest of the class. (btw its the danish grading system)

I really want to change the start of the bar plot, so its starts from -3 and moves upward. Ive tried playing with the y-axis' different limits and also "bottom =..." under the plt.bar() but it doesnt seem to fit...

Anyone who has any good sugestions?
Cheers and thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWuKT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with adding the "bottom" arg to the plt.bar() function.

I believe all you were missing is to subtract your negative value on the grading scale (-3) from the individual student's score.

See an example that worked for me here:

```
individual = np.array([10, 4, -3, 4, 4])
mean = [7, 7, 8, 7, 7]
assign = np.linspace(1, 5, 5)
plt.bar(assign, individual + 3, bottom=-3)
plt.plot(assign, mean, c='r')
plt.ylim([-3,13])
```

Comment: Thanks man! Thats works perfectly!  Can I perhaps ask you another question as well? if i wanted to make my y-axis a specifik range [-3,00,02,4,7,10,12] how will i do that best? I've looked into ticks but i still can't seem to get it to work..

Comment: Oh never mind, I got it ! Again thanks alot! :)

Comment: Glad I could help :]